# The weight of a Zero

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an ordered list of numbers (possibly with leading zeros), arrange the numbers vertically, then let all zeros drop all the way to the bottom and all overhangs drop to the bottom-most open slot. Output the resulting integers, removing leading zeros.

#### Worked Example

Say we were given the following as input:

```
['0000312941295', '239124000124581598', '32852353800451258', '10235923505185190', '1491359102149']
```

First we arrange it vertically:

```
0000312941295
239124000124581598
32852353800451258
10235923505185190
1491359102149
```

Then, column by column, drop the zeros "through" the other numbers so they rest on the bottom and "push" the other numbers up. This would result in the first couple steps being as follows:

```
2000312941295
339124000124581598
12852353800451258
10235923505185190
0491359102149
^

2300312941295
329124000124581598
14852353800451258
10235923505185190
0091359102149
 ^

2390312941295
328124000124581598
14252353800451258
10935923505185190
0001359102149
  ^

...

2391312941295
328524538124581598
14232323525451258
10915991001185190
0000350000049
                ^
```

Next, drop all overhangs as if gravity is pulling them down like sand.

```
2391312941295
3285245381245 1598
14232323525458258
10915991001181190
00003500000495
             ^

2391312941295
3285245381245  598
14232323525458158
10915991001181290
000035000004951
              ^

...

2391312941295
3285245381245
14232323525458159
10915991001181258
000035000004951908
                 ^
```

Finally, output these numbers, removing leading zeros. For our worked example, output:

```
[2391312941295, 3285245381245, 14232323525458159, 10915991001181258, 35000004951908]
```

For another example, suppose input of `[1234000,12345678,1234,12340608,12341234]`.

```
1234000
12345678
1234
12340608
12341234
```

Drop the zeros:

```
1234  
12345678
1234163
12340208
12340004
```

Drop the remaining overhanging digits:

```
1234  
1234567
12341638
12340208
12340004
```

Output is `[1234, 1234567, 12341638, 12340208, 12340004]`.

#### Rules

- The input *may* contain leading zeros. The output *must not* contain leading zeros.
- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: May we assume that the output numbers will not exceed our language's precision? (JS rounds `14232323525458159` to `14232323525458160`)

Comment: @ETHproductions I think that's a PPCG default.

Comment: `and all overhangs drop to the bottom-most open slot` was a good fix to my broken challenge :).

Comment: Yeah, @ETHproductions, that's a standard of my challenges. I must have missed it when copy-pasting the Rules section.

Comment: *The output must not contain leading zeros.* This applies only if you're printing the output as text, right?  If you produce a list / array of `int` in a language like C or x86 asm, I assume they can be stored the normal way, in fixed-width binary integers (which have leading `0` bits unless they're negative, or unsigned and very large).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, that's fine. Limitations/quirks of the language like fixed-width integers aren't applicable for that output restriction. For example, the *number* being talked about is still `1234`, regardless of what the actual binary representation looks like. You wouldn't say the number is `00..001234`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, mostly I was just nit-picking the wording.  I doubt anyone really thought you meant anything else.  BTW, does the input have to be in a format that can express (a variable number of) leading zeros?  e.g. that can differentiate between `01234` and `0001234`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, the input may contain leading zeros, so it should be able to handle that. I imagine for most languages, that means take input as a string.

Comment: And it has to be in base 10?  i.e. I couldn't apply this algorithm on the bits of binary integers?  Hmm, maybe fixed-width BCD integers would be good for x86 asm...  I could justify that because 32-bit x86 does still have instructions for manipulating BCD integer data (like [`AAA`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/AAA), so it's a native integer type.  Except that the instructions only work on a single byte at a time, designed for extended precision not fixed-width 16 or 32-bit BCD (I think).  Probably dealing with leading zeros in fixed-width ASCII strings is easier, though.

Comment: Is it allowed to replace leading zeros with leading spaces?  e.g. a C or asm function which modifies its input in place, where the input is an array of fixed-width char arrays like `char s[n][16]`?  Or would you require the output strings to be left-justified, so the most-significant digit of the actual number is the first character of each string?  It might be fun to implement this with x86 SIMD packed-compare and blend, and replacing leading zeros with spaces might be easier than shifting the rest of the buffer over.

Comment: @PeterCordes Input and output doesn't necessarily need to be in base-10 (that's in the allowed default I/O methods), so long as using a different base doesn't trivialize the task (that's a standard loophole). Secondly, I guess I didn't specify that the leading zeros must be removed *completely*, though that was the intent. I'm going to rule that replacing the zeros with spaces is not allowed, as outputting `.    1234` is very different than outputting `1234`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Z¬Þ€UZṚḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q0JrD8x41rQmNerhz1sMdPf///4@ONtCBQGMdQx0jHUsdEyhtGqujEG0EFLYEC5hAlUHYpjoWQJYpUM4CpMwYKGgB5IKUmwKxBVgpSBlIuSlEkSFQCKLAEkobgBVYgElLHQOIIhOwhRBlEC1gsdhYAA)

#### How it works

```
Z¬Þ€UZṚḌ  Main link. Argument: M (2D array / matrix)

Z         Zip; transpose M by reading columns as rows.
 ¬Þ€      Sort each row of the transpose by logical NOT, pushing 0's to the end.
    U     Upend; reverse all sorted rows of the transpose.
     Z    Zip again, restoring rows from columns. Overhangs rise to the top.
      Ṛ   Reverse the order of the rows.
       Ḍ  Decimal; convert the rows from base 10 to integer.
```

Comment: WHAT? 

As I was reading the question I was thinking: "Finally, there's no way someone can pull off less than 20 bytes for this". 

Madness

Comment: `Sort each row of the transpose by logical NOT, pushing 0's to the end.` Is this guaranteed to be a stable sort?

Comment: Yes, Jelly uses Python's `sorted`, which is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: I kind of like this commutative looking version: `ṚZẸÞ€ZṚḌ` :)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
ζεð†R0†R}øï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxDUJBDAPQVeiuoYiTs5SsQYsoQGIMJEZhA2hA9Nf/IVjk8P@RbFkvxvMF1zmXz/Ier9/9cbC1buM7nnMem@kCXl1h2@@aR8G7VM0EK1cNT3ow0qwTzg1holKMSKJsw16Q6qfVTn8)

Comment: Never seen `†` used before, nice one.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 118 bytes

```python
lambda l:[int(''.join(z))for z in zip(*map(lambda*a:['']*a.count(None)+[e for e in a if'0'<e]+['0']*a.count('0'),*l))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFNcoMwDIX3OYV3xsTNyH@pnSk9Qi/gekEbmNIhwCRk0VyeSiZpYYweH5KeRkw/89c46KWt3pe@Pn0ca9YfYjfMBee777EbipsQ7XhmN9YN7NZNRXmqp2JNLetD5DyV9e5zvGLJ2zg0YhsbRgUNFdSsaznwlyZtI8b/VHwRsuyFSMvcXOZLFTcRM/AySgeLx3HJuDZBaYsUn84rFzxRo73TxhkPYJ3SLkMFiAIecMo7FSBDGxRS/IaKJxmp4Z@DZLmTxU7UXzJltaHbabfaIYKAETuAUp68sMjRnGADufiUJI2utKE5uczK7Z/9Xd4D7OFBMsVZKKLBmr4KtTd@VaDhodAqpU3a0FZpWfLcXK79TPvNuztMZ/xhbKVV1RZEhcyp/OmVyztZfgE)

#### Ungolfed version

```python
def f(list_):
 max_len = max(len(x) for x in list_)
 transposed_list = zip(*[list(row)+(max_len-len(row))*[None] for row in list_])
 weighted_list = [['']*column.count(None)+[cell for cell in column if cell != '0' and cell != None]+['0']*column.count('0') for column in transposed_list]
 return [int(''.join(row)) for row in zip(*weighted_list)]
```

The first two lines are equivalent to `map(lambda*a...)`, the default behaviour if for `map` to fill with `None`s if one list is shorter than the other.
`e>'0'` is equivalent to `cell != '0' and cell != None`, because if it is any digit (1~9) it will have a higher codepoint, and (any) string is higher than `None`.

Comment: Care to post an ungolfed version of this?

Comment: @PeterCordes added the ungolfed version and a short explanation for some obscure points

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
md↔TmoÖ±miT↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcm9DcJQDATgXV5N4Z93kr1HOpSOAoSeKFBWyAQoe2QFsgmLmIuls86f78v7WTVuv/UzjdexfffxmHhU1bUJx9WyM2iXZp5qnciNUGQQ3QLm8BDpUMNpKpRkBBrQlNN6KpEvtjb/AQ)

#### Explanation

```
md↔Tm(Ö±mi)T↔  -- input as list of strings, example: ["103","32","258"]
            ↔  -- reverse: ["258","32","103"]
           T   -- transpose: ["231","520","83"]
    m(    )    -- with each line do (example with "520")
        mi     -- | convert each char to digit: [5,2,0]
      Ö±       -- | sort by signum (stable): [0,5,2]
               -- : [[2,3,1],[0,5,2],[8,3]]
   T           -- transpose: [[2,0,8],[3,5,3],[1,2]]
  ↔            -- reverse: [[1,2],[3,5,3],[2,0,8]]%
md             -- convert each to integer: [12,353,208]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 104 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.map{|x|x.ljust(99).chars}.transpose.map{|x|x.sort_by{|x|x<?1?x:?!}}.transpose.map{|x|x.join.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/dasMgFIDv8xSOXmSDVDzqAR3r8iAhFDtamtIlQQ2ktHn27Ghhu5ni3@fxfEc/HW7rabduP93d8W833h/zY@bXyxTiq7Vv/OvsfFh49K4P4xCOfzFh8HF/uOXDRw31/F6/LP9GXoau53HYd8uydv04RbZjTSmoKZBW08CyYqVUFqQmSjMaQGsSVdKgVKiMEBpBYoYgCFkaAsEgWJGhtkCU7mhXtoU/humaXKcmW9tiZE9WbJok@7VXLFs0WZK7YqClSp3yP0shJCytOTuYVAc9wvQHoW2qwLTrDw)

### Explanation

```ruby
->a{
  a.map{|x|x.ljust(99).chars}  # Fill spaces to make this rectangular
    .transpose.map{|x|
       x.sort_by{|x|x<?1?x:?!} # Treat all chars but " 1" as ! (see ascii table)
    }.transpose.map{|x|x.join.to_i} # Convert back to numbers
                       # note: if no leading 0s, eval x*'' , doesn't work here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
iRT_C_M!DMC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc0xDoAgDAXQq@j@B1SalFlXF@PWEFbdHFw8PZaWEGj5fYTne69a7@Msa9nHbV9rFQnwtWDCjITYK2UMMmucLIideU9g7UhnnCGLZqy3pkk3m2yqaWpmkEkjB6nXYIDtTAiOov3nzJ9YlvMP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```
m(+`^((.)*)(.+)(¶(?<-2>.)*)(?(2)_)$
$1$4$3
+`^((.)*)0(.*¶(?>(?<-2>.)*))([^0])
$1$4${3}0
^0+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYo9CgJBDEb7nGOKZBeX/ExgBmT3IOKqhYWFFmK3eC0P4MXGqKCBL3x5edfj7XQ5tHbGfj8jDtQRDj3h84HTeqXjB0yotKMESVJOBj@Tceje4vh3CTczb@mrLnZnmLmH1jjGRGuOOKhV0RwothfxWsC0uJpbYc4u6gWE464RdikulUFylUDxiPYC) Explanation: The first stage drops the overhanging digits as this makes it easier (edit: even easier for a 3-byte saving) for the second stage to drop the zeros. The third stage then removes leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), -p0 77 bytes

Old style counting: 79 bytes (`+2` for `p0`)

Give input as lines on STDIN without final newline (otherwise everything is seen as overhang and the final newline rises to the top as the input string crashes down). E.g.:

```
0000312941295
239124000124581598
32852353800451258
10235923505185190
1491359102149
```

It was a bit tricky to get the overhang dropping and the `0` dropping into one regex

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -p0
s/^.{@{+}}\K((0)|.+$)(.*
.{@{+}})((?(2)[1-9]|$))/$4$3$1/m while/|/g;s/^0+//mg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7CsMwDEV3f0UGD3ZDbMm2wCZDu/cT@thCGsiLpqVDkl@vq6EXjpCO4M7Ns6f8XpqCDIKBOi/2btbTWu779awU6M2UUitzEH@rlToqpy9YpdsmtbYySC/RDsXn0fWN3WxbcweU1g5tzsDx6FJgSDif0AVWPCkipSi8i@Q8@QgQCB1FgcB3YoAwEiYQGBKy4gdv32l@ddO45GqGHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking a character matrix as argument and returning a list of numbers.

```apl
⍎⍤1∘⍉' 0'(∩∘⊃,~,∩∘⊃∘⌽)⍤1⍨⍉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BSgMxEIbvPsXcYqFCJsnU5C32FZZtdxmou2V3Ebx4EUoVU9pDwYs3D/oQvkxeZJ3UamBm/nz/z0y5Wd8sH8p110xpfyqKtD1YBym@Q9FzO8KmX1U8cNeC4IGblmuuSjGW3PA4wNjlyP1KyFCxjOxD3fV35TjVsi3FfYofmHZvKT4r0Oo67b7y7@Vp/jj/17m/fs/O0fgp0WmqIW2PSsuzaIKTIgXK2IDGCZROHil4gdZ4Mpas19oRGsoMtZAgpQk9YdCZuYACxRKlrn4voLF5X7ZF0eLWX@Rl6IX@I2f6Aw)

`⍉` transpose the input (as we need to work on the columns)

`' 0'(`…`)⍤1⍨` apply the following tacit function to each row (sub-array of tensor rank 1) with `' 0'` as *right* argument (`⍨` swaps the arguments) :

`∩` intersection of the row and
 `∘` and
 `⊃` the first of `' 0'`
 (i.e. `row∩' '`; all the spaces from each row)

`,` followed by…

`~` the set difference
 (i.e. `row~' 0'`; the row but without spaces and zeros)

`,` followed by…

`∩` intersection of the row and
 `∘` and
 `⊃` the first
 `∘` of
 `⌽` the reversed `' 0'`
 (i.e. `row∩'0'`; all the zeros from each row)

`⍎⍤1` evaluate each row (sub-array of tensor rank 1)
`∘` of
`⍉` the transpose of that (i.e. each column; the now modified input rows)

Comment: The parenthesised bit is clever. It took me a while to understand the intention there, though I know what individual squiggles do. Once I understood it, it's easy to beat: `⍎⍤1∘⍉{⍵[⍋3|2×' 0'⍳⍵]}⍤1∘⍉` (`⎕io←0`) It may be golfable further, e.g. I didn't explore dyadic `⍋`

Comment: actually, the above is shorter as a complete program (not a train): `⍎⍤1⍉{⍵[⍋3|2×' 0'⍳⍵]}⍤1⍉⎕`

Comment: @ngn Such a different method merits own post. The pre- and post-processing is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 203 bytes

```ruby
->a{t=->b{b[0].zip(*b[1..-1])}
m=a.map{|s|s.size}.max
a.map!{|s|(s+" "*m)[0...m].chars}
a=t[a].map{|c|c.size.times{|i|" 0"[c[i]]&&(c.slice!(i)==?0?c.push(?0):c.unshift(" "))}
c}
t[a].map{|r|r.join.to_i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY//aoMwEID/9ylSB1W7NiQxgWRg@yAhDA1KM2orRmGr@uzuYmFLyK/vuPsu/Vj9rE2xns7lNBSnczVVmhj8dF16qDTF@ERNtkRtUeK27KbZzx5796wXeH5HG9wFmvr3GMWHNtMEY9wabK9l75eoLAZdmleune2WiwfX1n6a3RwjEmurnTH7fQrBm7P1LnVZUVzIxeJu9Nf0QrIPi8e7v7pmSEGSQT92if7r9nOPvx7ujofHp1uW1d27cUAF0gmBkVOmOCyRHFHCckUZBwq7kFQoGWjOpGC5yCUhXFAmNkgJIAWLCCoFVWSDXFGgEINbYqK@9uMtuBq9WU3UoReL3nSQ/dmPaLNwsAT3EVHO8jCh/qsVQETBuVWnMvQBSSL8gXAVOpBm/QU)

A lambda accepting an array of strings and returning an array of ints. I feel like I'm missing something; this feels enormous :/

```ruby
->a{
  t = -> b { b[0].zip(*b[1..-1]) }     # t is a lambda that transposes 2D arrays
  m = a.map{ |s| s.size }.max          # m is the maximum input string length
  a.map!{ |s| (s+" "*m)[0...m].chars } # Right-pad every string to the same length
  a = t[a].map{ |c|                    # Transpose a, and for every row (column)
    c.size.times{ |i|                  # For every character in the column
      " 0"[c[i]] && (                  # If the character is 0 or space
        c.slice!(i) == ?0 ?            # Remove it from the column, and if it was 0,
          c.push(?0) :                 # Push a 0 to the end (bottom) of the column, else
          c.unshift(" ")               # Add a space to the top of the column
      )
    }
    c
  }
  t[a].map{ |r| r.join.to_i }          # Transpose a back, and parse each row to int
}
```

Comment: I [outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156468/21830) this (for now)

Comment: @Unihedron Wow, you beat me by 50%. You've got my +1 for sure.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```apl
⍎⍤1⍉{⍵[⍒⌈9÷⍨⎕d⍳⍵]}⍤1⍉⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3PisIwEIfvfQpvPRVmkowmz7J4KJaKULDoSZa9Lf5BU1TwDTx4F/EB9k3mRbq/ag1M8s03vyR5XWXFKq/m02xS5cvlbNJqc5nNdX0k3f@CywWYjR@927pGa12i203Zamw0Xlnj7lvj40vjWQ/b8PfUeEO00HiHHv/0GagW19oy0fUpJSzLJjiUpIPU2MDGQWIXzxI8pDVejBXriZywkc4xwQQUCXvhQJ1zgSExAqVJlrz/YGO7F7sASIYj32N/0JA@5mX/AQ)

based on Adam's solution